# Flatten nested dictionary to list of key:value pair

Tags: python, json, api, jq

I am querying company house API for an anti-corruption investigation and I get results in a nested JSON which can be seen [here](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/search-overview/OfficerSearch-resource.html). I would like to transform this dictionary into a simple `{key:value, key:value}` format, where if I have nested objects or lists the keys merge in the flattened key string.

The problem is also that some items returned by the API might not necessarily have all the key:value pairs, as some of these are optional. **If the key:value pair is absent then I'd like to insert an `NA`.**

Here's the JSON at its fullest - some query results might not have all these entries though.

```
{
   "items" : [
      {
         "address" : {
            "address_line_1" : "string",
            "address_line_2" : "string",
            "care_of" : "string",
            "country" : "string",
            "locality" : "string",
            "po_box" : "string",
            "postal_code" : "string",
            "premises" : "string",
            "region" : "string"
         },
         "address_snippet" : "string",
         "appointment_count" : "integer",
         "date_of_birth" : {
            "month" : "integer",
            "year" : "integer"
         },
         "description" : "string",
         "description_identifiers" : [
            "integer"
         ],
         "kind" : "string",
         "links" : {
            "self" : "string"
         },
         "matches" : [
            {
               "address_snippet" : [
                  "integer"
               ],
               "snippet" : [
                  "integer"
               ],
               "title" : [
                  "integer"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "snippet" : "string",
         "title" : "string"
      }
   ],
   "items_per_page" : "integer",
   "kind" : "string",
   "start_index" : "integer",
   "total_results" : "integer"
}
```

Reusing some old JQ code I managed to get to creating two lists one containing all keys and one containing all values (see jqplay [here](https://jqplay.org/s/XcUok7HXWT)).

Here's an example for just a bit of the dictionary, to get the idea:

```
{
   "items_address_address_line_1" : "string",
   "items_address_address_line_2" : "string"
   "items_address_care_of" : "string",
   "items_address_country" : "string",
   "items_address_locality" : "string",
   "items_address_po_box" : "string",
   "items_address_postal_code" : "string",
   "items_address_premises" : "string",
   "items_address_region" : "string"
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `items` array always has one element, make use of `--stream` option;

```
reduce (inputs|select(length == 2)) as $p
({}; .[$p[0]|map(strings)|join("_")] = $p[1])
```

since `inputs` is used, `-n` option is also required.

Comment: This works very well! I am using the [jq](https://pypi.org/project/jq/) library for python - not sure how i can give the command the `-n --stream` flag from there...or there are other ways to execute jq commands from python?

Comment: I don't know anything about python, never worked with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), specifically [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

d = {
    "items" : [
        {
            "address" : {
                "address_line_1" : "string",
                "address_line_2" : "string",
                "care_of" : "string",
                "country" : "string",
                "locality" : "string",
                "po_box" : "string",
                "postal_code" : "string",
                "premises" : "string",
                "region" : "string"
            },
            "address_snippet" : "string",
            "appointment_count" : "integer",
            "date_of_birth" : {
                "month" : "integer",
                "year" : "integer"
            },
            "description" : "string",
            "description_identifiers" : [
                "integer"
            ],
            "kind" : "string",
            "links" : {
                "self" : "string"
            },
            "matches" : [
                {
                    "address_snippet" : [
                        "integer"
                    ],
                    "snippet" : [
                        "integer"
                    ],
                    "title" : [
                        "integer"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "snippet" : "string",
            "title" : "string"
        }
    ],
    "items_per_page" : "integer",
    "kind" : "string",
    "start_index" : "integer",
    "total_results" : "integer"
}


x = json_normalize(d['items'], sep="_")
print(x.to_string())
# print(x.keys()) # handy, as you may get "lost" with many keys
# x.to_dict(
```

---

```
 address_address_line_1 address_address_line_2 address_care_of address_country address_locality address_po_box address_postal_code address_premises address_region address_snippet appointment_count date_of_birth_month date_of_birth_year description description_identifiers    kind links_self                                            matches snippet   title
0                 string                 string          string          string           string         string              string           string         string          string           integer             integer            integer      string               [integer]  string     string  [{'address_snippet': ['integer'], 'snippet': [...  string  string
```

---

Notes:

1. You can reuse `json_normalize` to flatten further nested elements (lists) as needed.
2. I normally un-flatten all objects into new dataframes first and then merge everything into a new `master_df` with all `keys` flattened. Hope it makes sense to you, otherwise please comment.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying out both solutions.